# Matrix multiplication proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have to prove

$A^HAB = A^HAC \implies AB = AC.$

Where $A^H$ is hermitian of $A.$

All I can do is to write summation equation and then don't know what to do, while this strategy was working well on other examples

Can someone please help

Comment: Hermitian what? You mean the conjugate transpose?

Comment: Yes, conjugate transpose

Comment: Hint: Show that $\operatorname{Ker}\left(A^H A\right) = \operatorname{Ker}A$.

Comment: In our text book we don't read kernel yet but I'll try to find out what it is. Thanks

Comment: In other words, show that a vector $v$ satisfies $A^H A v = 0$ if and only if it satisfies $A v = 0$.

Comment: can we multiply both sides by V^H on left?